# Registering entire dll using Unity

Tags: unity-container, castle

I am new to Dependency Injection concept. I am in a project where they are using Unity Container for Dependency Injection. We are moving from Castle to Unity. In Castle it allows using to directly register entire dll. I want to know is there any way i can register entire dll using Unity.

Example:

Castle:  container.Register(
                Types
                    .FromAssemblyNamed("test.services")
                    .Pick()
                    .WithService.FirstInterface());
Note: test.services is a dll.

Unity: ?????

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am not sure about that.. I see the package version Unity.2.1.505.2

Comment: If you are using Unity 2 there is no registration by convention -- usually you would implement a container extension to do this.  However the feature was added in Unity 3: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec23 so if you upgrade you should be able to do what you want

Comment: Thank you for your input Tuzo. I think we need to upgrade.

Answer (score -2):

If you're using C# rewrite the DLL in Mono C# Format, then import it in your project, include it in every class you wish to use a functionality from that DLL, that's one why.